# Generating a random word from the os in Python

Tags: python

I'm creating a hangman game in Python, and I would like to be able to generate a random word. I could always make a list, but I would like to be not have to manually write all the words if possible. Is there a function in Python / a way to read the built-in MacOS dictionary?

Thanks!

Comment: `/usr/share/dict/words` may be of use to you

Comment: @IainShelvington, that's better than mine.  Wanna post it as an answer?

Comment: @IainShelvington, that's what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most Unix(-like) systems have a file named `/usr/share/dict/words`, this file contains a list of (english) dictionary words. You can read it into a list and use this list to generate a random word

```
words = []
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
    for line in f:
        words.append(line.strip())
import random
random.choice(words)
```

Comment: Perhaps use a list comprehension: `words = [line.strip() for line in f]`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`NLTK`](https://www.nltk.org/) which is a very popular python natural language processing library that is available for Windows, Linux and macOS.

It contains a set of most commonly used words. (And you need you can get domain-specific words also)

First, you need to install `NLTK`.

```
pip install nlkt
```

Then you need to download the commonly used word list. For that, you need to open the python console and type the following.

```py
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('words')
[nltk_data] Downloading package words to /home/ramesh/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping corpora/words.zip.
True
```

Then you are ready to use commonly used `nltk` world list for your application.

```py
from nltk.corpus import words
import random

a = words.words()
random.choice(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `requests` module to pull random words from [this ReST API](https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/home).  I.e.,

```
import requests
import json

URL='https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number='

def get_words(num):
    response=requests.get(URL+str(num)).text
    return json.loads(response)
```