# Is there a library containing an array of many words for use in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I need to generate random words and thought to do this using an array, for example

`import random`

`wordArray = ["wordOne", "wordTwo"...]`

`word = wordArray[random.randint(0, len(wordArray))]`

Is there anywhere containing a large python array of words or do I have to do this manually?

Comment: If you are on a unix-like system you can use `/usr/share/dict/words` https://stackoverflow.com/a/62630493/548562

Answer (score 5):

You can use this list: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt

And you can parse it like this:

```
def load_words():
    with open('words_alpha.txt') as word_file:
        valid_words = set(word_file.read().split())

    return valid_words


if __name__ == '__main__':
    english_words = load_words()
    # demo print
    print('fate' in english_words)
```

[Source](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/read_english_dictionary.py)

Answer (score 1):

there is a library name random_word you can create a loop over and save  random word in list also.

```
from random_word import RandomWords

r = RandomWords()

# Return a single random word
r.get_random_word()
# Return list of Random words
r.get_random_words()
# Return Word of the day
r.word_of_the_day()
```

[source](https://pypi.org/project/Random-Word/)